# Android Studio: Trouble specifying drawable resource

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable

I am trying to specify an menu icon for an Action Bar.  I'm using Android Studio 1.2.  My XML code follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_connect"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_bluetooth_white_24dp.png"
        android:title="@string/menu_connect"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />
</menu>
```

The compiler complains about anything that I put after "android:icon=".  Depending on what I've changed last, I get:  "No resource found that matches the given name" or "String types not allowed" (among other errors).

I've tried suggestions from several posts.  I cleared the Intellij cache and rebuilt everything and nothing changed.  One post suggested that perhaps android:icon wasn't supported in earlier API versions so I set minSdkVersion to 23 (my current SDK version) in my module build script.  I re-sync'd and again nothing changed.

I had some trouble figuring out how to set up the drawable directories for multiple resolution bitmaps.  (Why doesn't Android Studio just create them when creating a new project?)  I now have them (drawable-hdpi etc.) set up as siblings to the drawable directory.  I think that's right.  At least they appear to be correct in the Android directory view.  Yeah, I'm a newbie.

Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: You should remove _-.png_ from _android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_bluetooth_white_24dp.png"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_bluetooth_white_24dp.png"
```

with:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_bluetooth_white_24dp"
```

You do not use file extensions when referring to resources from anywhere inside of Android.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  I swear that I tried exactly that on at least a couple of occasions, but I probably still had my drawable directories crossed up at the time.